# i pass data in HttpURLConnection outputstream but HttpServletrequest inputstream is empty

Tags: servlets, inputstream, httpurlconnection

Here is client code

```
public static void uploadFiles() {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(Parameter.UPLOAD_FILES_DIR), "{*.dat}")) {
        for (Path path : ds) {
            System.out.println(path);
            URL url = new URL(Parameter.UPLOAD_URL);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 20);
            conn.setReadTimeout(1000 * 20);

            send(conn, path);
            receive(conn);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void send(HttpURLConnection conn, Path path) throws Exception {
    try (
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path.toFile()))
            ) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, c);
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
public static void receive(HttpURLConnection conn) throws Exception {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))) {
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK != conn.getResponseCode()) {
            throw new Exception("Uploader response code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Post request");
    System.out.println(request.getContentLength());
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
    ) {
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(str);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()))) {
        bw.write("Close connection!!!");
    }

}
```

When i run client code in server console out appears

> Post refquest
>   -1

request.getContentLength() always return -1
Why i cant send bytes to the servlet? Here is contains of file which bytes i am trying to send 
["192","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","US"] ["194","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","US"]

Comment: It it necessary to use `HttpURLConnection`? There are more comfortable libraries out there. Maybe it's better when you use `conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` or `conn.setChunkedStreamingMode()`?

Comment: Forgot to add, client receive response and prints in System.out "Close connection!!!"

Comment: Unfortunatelly, to use HttpURLConnection is base requirement, like not use conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(), conn.setChunkedStreamingMode()

Comment: Resovled. Problem was in "/" symbol in the end of url. it was absent. But in this case servlet has responded.

Answer (score 0):

Resovled. Problem was in "/" symbol in the end of url. it was absent. But in this case servlet has responded.